# Writing a dictionary value that is a list without brackets to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, file-writing

I have a dictionary, `d` with the following structure:

```
{'k':[5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8], 'c':[6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9]}
```

I want to write this to a .csv file that looks like:

```
k, 5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8
c, 6, 3, 1, 2, -3, 4, 9
```

I tried the following code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,d[key]))
```

This, unfortunately produces the following:

```
k, [5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8]
c, [6, 3, 1, 2, -3, 4, 9]
```

The solution I have is to just run a `tr` or `sed` command after, but there must to be a way to just write it properly the first time, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest first building the lists that you want to write out as a CSV:

```
>>> [[k] + v for k, v in d.items()]
[['k', 5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8], ['c', 6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9]]
```

From there your original code will work, but I'd also suggest using `csv.writer` rather than rolling your own formatting:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in [[k] + v for k, v in d.items()]:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Definitely using `csv` module is correct way

Comment: Also works great! This is one I'm much more familiar with. I'm not sure why I didn't use CSV to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

```
d = {'k':[5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8], 'c':[6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9]}

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
        print(key, *d[key], sep=', ', file=f)
```

Prints to file:

```
k, 5, -2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8
c, 6, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I did not know that you could use the `print()` command like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `join`:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, lst in dct.items():
        lst = ','.join(map(str, lst))
        f.write('%s,%s\n' % (k, lst))
```